# Getting All form elements during httpwebrequest -- need assistance

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to do is to create an httpwebrequest and navigate to a website, lets say a website that requires the user to create a username and password on the site. I know that I can use Firefoxes plugin LiveHeaders and fill the form capturing the post from the headers.

From this section I can find where my username and password would be and replace my username and password with variables like this:

```
Dim postData As String = "referer=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.zybez.net%2Findex.php%3Fapp%3Dcore%26module%3Dglobal%26section%3Dlogin&username=" & TextBox1.Text & "&password=" & TextBox2.Text & "&rememberMe=1"
```

What I am trying to do or need to figure out is how get those inputs during a request to a website rather than having to enter the information, capture the headers and then manually have to edit them for the POST.

I've been reading for about 2 weeks straight and I cannot seem to find a solution as to how someone can navigate to a website....make a request (be either httpwebrequest or webrequest) extract all the form input elements of a website and print/get them into a string and the read the string into a richtextbox.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim logincookie As CookieContainer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click

Dim postData As String = "referer=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.zybez.net%2Findex.php%3Fapp%3Dcore%26module%3Dglobal%26section%3Dlogin&username=" & TextBox1.Text & "&password=" & TextBox2.Text & "&rememberMe=1"
Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(Textbox1.text), HttpWebRequest)
postReq.Method = "POST"
postReq.KeepAlive = True
postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postReq.Referer = TextBox1.Text
postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
postreqstream.Close()
Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
logincookie = tempCookies
Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
```

This code will navigate to a website that is loaded into textbox1 and read the html code into the rich text box.

BUT.....from reading the answering above about:

```
For Each key As String In HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys
Dim value as string = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form(key)
Next
```

This code does not work in my application anywhere. I get an error code of:

'HttpContext' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

So in summary how does one using my method above get all the form input elements of a website during the request?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue using the HTMLAgilityPack or is this still a problem?